# What this do and where to use, how it is useful? C# Class type?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, types

So, I am using 'Grid' asset for unity engine for make grid based 2d game,

From its script, there is class name like this,

```
public class SimpleGridEditor<TGridBuilder, TPoint> : GLEditor<TGridBuilder>
    where TGridBuilder : MonoBehaviour, ITileGrid<TPoint>
    where TPoint : IGridPoint<TPoint>  
{
```

So I am curious about SimpleGridEditor<{TGridBuilder, TPoint> part.

What is this?, Why it used, where, when should I use like that?

I can understand type at parameters like,

void SomeFunc(int a, string b){}

but what is class's type?

Thanks.

Comment: Please read the tags you are using, the tag [tag:unity] explicitly says it is not for the unity game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are known as [Generic Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx).

Generic classes allow you to perform the same operations on data regardless of it's type.

A classic example is `List<T>`.

Regardless of whether or not you have an integer list `new List<int>()` or a string list `new List<string>()`, you can still `.Add()` an item, to the list, `.Remove()` an item from the list, etc.  The underlying type of the list doesn't matter from list to list instance.  This gives an incredible amount of reuse and flexibility to your code.

`<TGridBuilder, TPoint>` are both placeholders for a type that *will* provided once an instance of the type is instantiated.  They are not a type in and of themselves yet.  You provide the actual types when you instantiate the class:

```
var instance = new SimpleGridEditor<SlowGridBuilder, LargePoint>();
```

where `SlowGridBuilder` and `LargePoint` are two actual concrete types that you can reference.

This allows for later methods in the `SimpleGridEditor` to use those concrete types and perform actions on them.

In your case, there are also [Type Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on your generic parameters.  This limits the type of class that can be used as a Generic Class Type in order to focus the scope and ensure that operations within the class can be completed.  For instance, if you could pass a `WaterBuffalo` instance for `TPoint` instead of `IGridPoint`, your class' functionality would probably not work as intended.

Comment: I can understand 'where' keyword, but still I don't understand well about [SimpleGridEditor<TGridBuilder, TPoint>] part.

Comment: TGridBuilder and TPoint are type parameters where you are expected to pass a class.

Comment: OK Thx. But if I use just like 'class SimpleGridEditor : GLEditor' (no type), what inconvenient will I have?

Comment: You can't.  It's not valid syntax and it won't compile.  If your target requires generic types you need to also instantiate it with concrete types satisfying the generic constraints.  You **must** provide the type arguments.

Comment: Then fundamentally, why use class type structure like above?

Comment: To guarantee similar type behavior based on how the class is created that will be perpetuated to methods inside of the class.  Just looking at the signature isn't enough to tell you WHY they chose that particular class definition.

Comment: Much thanks. One final quetion. Do you know actual code example page to show usefulness of this class type issue?

Comment: @leegod if you want the official documentation, you can look at this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx